# Exercise on $C^\infty$ function from $\mathbb{RP}^1$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: geometry

Consider the identification space $$X=([0,1]×[0,1])/\sim,\ \ (u,0)\sim (1-u,1),(0,v)\sim (1,1-v).$$
I have to show that the function $$f:X \to R,\ \ f([u,v])=(1+\operatorname{cos}2\pi v)\operatorname {cos} 2\pi u$$ is $C^\infty$, calculate $df_p$ in every $p\in X$ and determinate where $df_p=0.$

Actually I noticed that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^1$, but I'm new to this type of exercise and I don't know what to do here. According to the theory, I should find an atlas for $X$ and verify that $f\circ \phi_i^{-1}:A_i \subset \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is $C^\infty $ for every $i$ (here  $(U_i,\phi_i,A_i)$ are the charts of $X$). However I'm pretty sure that there is an quicker way; thank you in advance for the help.